# Providing a method implementation at runtime in java

Tags: java

I have a `swing` `class` with a `JTextArea` which is used to write some `java` code. From the `swing` `class` I call a method in other `class(say X)` that returns me some value. Say,

```
X x = new X();
int result[] = x.getResult(int p[]);
```

This `X class` needs to be present in the same directory, otherwise my code does not compile. So I make a `X class` and make a function `getResult` that returns an empty array. This method is given its implementation during runtime by the user(in the `TextArea`).

I am able to compile the class at runtime using `ProcessBuilder` after writing the contents of the `TextArea` to that file. The problem is this - When I run the code in my IDE ( IntelliJ Idea), then the function returns the proper value it should have returned because of the user code as the file is overwritten. But when I pack my project in a jar, then it returns only the empty array. The new code is written to the file in the same directory, but it takes the value given by the initial function (which is probably packed in the jar file).

How do I possibly get the correct return value?

Comment: If you make X an `interface`, when you try to create a new one it will force you to provide an implementation that way.  I'm not sure how to fully help solve your problem, but hopefully this may point you in a good direction

Comment: @RhinoFeeder : Is it possible to exclude X from the jar file, and place it in the same directory instead, so that it is able to just compile. Later on, during runtime , I will be able to overwrite it and recompile it??

Comment: Agree that interfaces are your friends here. I'd also add that if you have no idea what class will be used until runtime, you probably want a factory method to obtain the instance object... and you may need/want to have that factory use reflection to select the class.

Comment: @Keshlam : Could you be a bit more specific please. I have defined the interface. But now I cannot call the function from the main class..